# How I can list all sbt dependencies?

Tags: scala, sbt

I need to list all sbt dependencies in order to check if already exists a debian package ([I also notice that there is a DEB package](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html) but it seems that external dependencies are not packaged).

At the moment I did a list of sbt dependencies with the following steps:

1. [Install sbt manually](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Manual-Installation.html)
2. I created a simple script that extract all jar files in ~/.ivi2 directory (excluding sbt jar). Here the result of the execution:

   ```
   Group;Artifact;Artifact+Version
   org.scala-lang;jline;jline-2.10.5
   org.scala-lang;scala-compiler;scala-compiler-2.10.5
   org.scala-lang;scala-library;scala-library-2.10.5
   org.scala-lang;scala-reflect;scala-reflect-2.10.5
   com.jcraft;jsch;jsch-0.1.46
   org.scalamacros;quasiquotes_2.10;quasiquotes_2.10-2.0.1
   jline;jline;jline-2.11
   com.thoughtworks.paranamer;paranamer;paranamer-2.6
   org.json4s;json4s-ast_2.10;json4s-ast_2.10-3.2.10
   org.json4s;json4s-core_2.10;json4s-core_2.10-3.2.10
   org.scala-lang.modules;scala-pickling_2.10;scala-pickling_2.10-0.10.0
   org.scala-tools.sbinary;sbinary_2.10;sbinary_2.10-0.4.2
   org.fusesource.jansi;jansi;jansi-1.4
   org.spire-math;json4s-support_2.10;json4s-support_2.10-0.6.0
   org.spire-math;jawn-parser_2.10;jawn-parser_2.10-0.6.0
   ```

Do you think is the right way to list all sbt dependencies?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a nice `sbt plugin` for that:
https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph

Simply adding to `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.8.0")
```

Calling `sbt dependencyTree` you can get an "ascii graph" like:

```
...
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:4.10.2
[info]   | | +-com.spatial4j:spatial4j:0.4.1
[info]   | | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:4.10.2
[info]   | | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:4.10.2
[info]   | |   +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:4.10.2
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:4.10.2
[info]   |   +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:4.10.2
[info]   |   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:4.10.2
[info]   |   |
[info]   |   +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:4.10.2
[info]   |   +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:4.10.2
[info]   |   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:4.10.2
[info]   |   |
[info]   |   +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:4.10.2
[info]   |     +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:4.10.2
...
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but I need to list only sbt dependencies as a build tool not as a specific project. So I need to list what external library sbt requires. Do you know how I can list all sbt (as build tool) dependencies?

Comment: Did you try to `git clone git@github.com:sbt/sbt.git && cd sbt` then `git checkout 0.13.9` and `sbt dependencyTree`?

Comment: Yes, I tried and I have the following error:  
`[info] Set current project to sbtRoot (in build file:/tmp/sbt/)`  
`[error] Not a valid command: dependencyTree`  
`[error] Not a valid project ID: dependencyTree`  
`[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)`  
`[error] Not a valid key: dependencyTree (similar: dependencyOverrides, dependency-overrides, sbt-dependency)`  
`[error] dependencyTree`  
`[error]               ^`

Comment: You have to add the `sbt-dependency-graph` as described in the *answer* first.

Comment: >> `addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.9.2")`

Comment: I had some problem on installing the **sbt-dependency-graph** and I followed the step by step of this article [here](https://support.snyk.io/hc/en-us/articles/360004167317-How-to-install-the-SBT-dependency-graph-plugin-to-test-Scala-projects-with-Snyk-CLI) and that worked pretty well.

Comment: This is great. But it came by default with sbt 1.4.9 for me

Answer (score 9):

In case the dependency hierarchy provided by `sbt-dependency-graph` is not needed, the following might be useful:

```
sbt 'show dependencyClasspathFiles'
```

Comment: Nice! Simplest answer I've seen so far!

Answer (score 1):

Just adding here how to install **sbt-dependency-graph**, I think that is relevant for the question.

---

IMPORTANT:

The answer is just the part related to **sbt-dependency-graph**. The complete answer (sbt+scala+homebrew+plugin) you may find [here](https://support.snyk.io/hc/en-us/articles/360004167317-How-to-install-the-SBT-dependency-graph-plugin-to-test-Scala-projects-with-Snyk-CLI)

---

In order to use the Snyk CLI to test Scala projects, you will need to install the Sbt dependency graph plugin.

Installing the Sbt dependency graph plugin for sbt 0.13
Prerequisites

Ensure you have installed Scala.

Ensure you have installed Sbt and ran sbt.

NOTE: The steps below will install the Sbt dependency plugin as a global plugin.

1. First navigate to the correct directory by typing the following
   command: `cd ~/.sbt`
2. This will take you to the Sbt directory. From there you will need to
   navigate to the 0.13 directory. Typing the `ls` command will show if
   0.13 and/or 1.0 exists in the directory
3. Navigate to 0.13 by typing: `cd 0.13` and then make a directory called
   plugins by typing: `mkdir plugins`
4. Navigate to the new directory by typing: `cd plugins` and then proceed
   to create a file called “plugins.sbt” by typing: `touch plugins.sbt`
5. Edit the plugins.sbt file via your preferred editor
6. Add the following line to the file:

```
addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.10.0-RC1")
```

7. save the changes
8. Take the following steps for the 1.0 directory. Check if 1.0 exists
   by typing `ls` in the sbt directory:

   - If the 1.0 does NOT exist in the sbt directory, type `mkdir 1.0` in the sbt directory
   - If 1.0 exists in the directory, run the following command: `cd ~/.sbt/1.0`
   - Make a directory called “plugins” in that folder by typing: `mkdir plugins`
     Copy the existing “plugins.sbt” file from the 0.13 directory to the current 1.0 directory by typing the following: `cp ../0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt ./plugins`
   - Validate that the plugin has been installed correctly by running the following command:  `sbt "-Dsbt.log.noformat=true" dependencyTree` [important](/questions/tagged/important) **This should be tested in the directory of the project** and by running the command will generate the dependency graph. You can also run it each time you want to generate the dependency graph)