# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse$default$3()Z

Tags: java, json, scala, apache-spark

I am getting error while running spark using **spark submit** , but this works perfectly fine when I **run a test using test FunSuite**. 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse$default$3()Z

What I am doing: 
1. I am running the test case using funSuit and it is able to use the parse method as expected.

2. When I am running the code on local machine by creating the fat jar file it is giving me this issue. 
   I am not able to understand how test suit can be different than what is there in the jar file.

Here is the code

```
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.{compact, parse, render}
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, Extraction, Formats}

val test = Testrdd
  .map { line =>
    implicit val jsonFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats
    val parsedJson = parse(line)
    val Testuuid = (parsedJson \ "testid").extract[String]
   (Testuuid)
 }
```

Here is the sbt file

```
 enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, UniversalPlugin, BuildInfoPlugin)

    name := "spark-scala"

    version := "0.1"

    scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

    parallelExecution in Test := false
    fork in Test := true

    libraryDependencies ++= {
      val akkaVersion = "2.5.23"
      val jacksonVersion = "2.9.9"
      val sparkVersion = "2.4.2"

      Seq(
        "com.amazonaws" % "amazon-kinesis-client" % "1.10.0",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % jacksonVersion,
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % jacksonVersion,
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % jacksonVersion,
        "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.8.5",
        "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
        "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided",
        "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % "provided",
        "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion % "provided",
        "com.github.seratch" %% "awscala" % "0.8.2",
        "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.9.2",
        "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.7.4",
        "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion,
        "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % akkaVersion,
        "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.1.8",
        "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % akkaVersion,
        "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.2.6",
        "org.rogach" %% "scallop" % "3.3.1",
        "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.6.8", //"3.5.5",
        "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.2.0-SNAP10",
        "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.0-SNAP10" % "test",
        "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.14.0" % "test",
        "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % akkaVersion % "test",
        "com.twitter" %% "algebird-core" % "0.13.5",
        "black.ninia" % "jep" % "3.8.2",
        "com.twitter" %% "chill" % "0.9.3",
        "ml.dmlc" % "xgboost4j-spark" % "0.80",
        "com.sksamuel.avro4s" %% "avro4s-core" % "2.0.2",
        "org.moeaframework" % "moeaframework" % "2.12",
        "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value,
        "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value,
        "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % scalaVersion.value,
        "org.apache.commons" % "commons-math3" % "3.6.1",
        "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-avro" % "2.4.5"
      )
    }

    assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
      case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
      case x => MergeStrategy.first
    }

    val jepLocation = {
      import sys.process._
      "pip show jep" #| "grep Location" !!
    }
    val jepPath = {
      jepLocation.replace("\n","").split(": ", -1)(1) + "/jep"
    }
    javaOptions in Test += s"-Djava.library.path=${sys.env.getOrElse("JEP_PATH", jepPath)}"
```

Comment: Can you show your build.sbt or pom.xml file ?

Comment: Might be the Jackson jar is not available in the classpath, there are two options, create a fat jar with all the dependency and run it on the spark server or pass the application jar along with any jars included with the --jars option will be automatically transferred to the cluster.

Comment: forgot to mention I am using fat jar and I am running the jar on  my local machine.

Comment: are you using which IDE, if it is Intillij can invalidate cache & restart IDE & check if it is running in local or not. ?

Comment: I tied that... no result. bye the way I am building jar from command line using "sbt clean assembly" .. I think intellij will not affect right?

Comment: Such errors occur due to dependency conflicts and one of them do not have the definition of the method. Check if there are multiple versions of your jackson dependency in the libraries.

Comment: why are u using spark avro higher version 2.4.5 & other libraries are 2.4.2 ?

Comment: @Sangeeta... Thank you , can you let me know how to check that and if that happens to be the case how to resolve that. I feel this might be the reason.

Comment: @Srinivas I just used the lates avro library.

Comment: @Amit refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583171/how-i-can-list-all-sbt-dependencies. May be it can help.

Comment: @Sangeeta Thank you very much it was very good advcie. however dependency graph doesn't show anything else except below json4s.